# Dependency verify functions call mockito

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, verify

I want create unit test to test a class which contains another object. I have created a mock to this second object.

When I test a method of my first class, I want verify if the functions of the second object are called. For this, I use the function `verify(mock).myfunction();`

My problem is that the same function of my object 2 can be called by several function of my first class.

When I write the test class, I write a test function by function but it seems that the "times" isn't reset at the beginning of a test method.

I don't know if I am clear, therefore, an example :

```
public class Main  {
    public Object o = createObject();

    public void function1(){
        o.function();
    }

    public void function2(){
        o.function();
    }


    public Object createObject() {
        return new Object() ;
    }


public class MainTest {
    private static Main main;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        final Object mockO = mock(Object.class);

        main = new Main() {
            @Override
            public Object createObject() {
                return mockO;
            }
            }; 
    }

    @Test
    public void testfunction1(){
        verify(main.world[0], never()).function();
        main.function1();
        verify(main.world[0]).function();
    }

    @Test
    public void testfunction2(){
        verify(main.world[0], never()).function();
        main.function2();
        verify(main.world[0]).function();
    }
```

If I test `testfunction1()` and `testfunction2()` ignored, it's work.

If I test `testfunction2()` and `testfunction1()` ignored, it's work.

But if the two tests are executed, I have an error :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked:
Object.function();
Never wanted here : 
-> at test.MainTest.testfunction1
but invoked here :
at source.Main.function2
```

How I can test independently the two functions?

Comment: Your `setUp()` method is `static`... Why?

Comment: I have an error if I remove static "java.lang.Exception : Method setUp() should be static"

Comment: Hmmm, would you consider switching to TestNG? :p This error message is more than often reported as a bug in component x and y when googled for... TestNG has never had such problems.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your `setUp()` method into something else, make it a non-static method, and make it `@Before` and not `@BeforeClass`:

```
private Main main;

@Before
public void initMain()
{
    // what you already do
}
```

`@BeforeClass` methods run once before all tests in a class, while `@Before` methods are run once before *each* test.

Comment: I have already a method with "@Before"
"@Before
 public void init() throws AWTException {
  main.init();
 }
"
I have try to remove "static" but I have an error "java.lang.Exception : Method setUp() should be static

Comment: Can you rename your `setUp()` method to something else, like in my example? I am used to TestNG which has no such limitations on method naming...

Comment: I have test to reset the mock each end of test method and it seems to work.

Comment: There is no need to reset mocks. Check that you are using JUnit 4. Then check that you are using annotation `@Before` (not `@BeforeClass`) on instance method (not static method). Method annotated with `@Before` is called before each test method. You need that, because you need to recreate the mock before each test, so the tests are isolated.